# Is it possible to adjust the pinning distance depending on screen size in XCode Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

For example, I want no pinning on a small screen like an iPhone 5, but on the new iPhones, I do want some amount of pinning. Is there any way this can be done? I'm really new to Auto Layout and Swift and have been thrown into the deep end at work.

Comment: What do you mean by "pinning"?  What are you trying to "pin" together? Can you offer examples of what you have already tried?

Comment: Hi Scott. Sorry, I'm not sure if I have the right terminology. What I mean is adding constraints that put an element at, say, 100 pixels from the safe area on a large device. However, on a small device, there's not enough space for this to be possible, so I want no set distance from the safe area. I guess the proper term is using the Pin tool to set this distance. I have tried googling for some way to scale this distance depending on screen size, but I haven't been successful in finding any solution.

Comment: Take a look at "trait variations" and "size classes". This let's you create different spacings/paddings for various device sizes. You should make layout decisions based on those size classes and not on iPhone 5 vs. iPhone 13 Pro. Check out the "Device Size Classes" section here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should not make layout decisions based on screen size, or device model, directly.

A constraint has a priority if that priority is low, the system may try to accommodate it, if it can.  The highest priority is 1000 if I remember properly.

In this case, if you want a stand-off on screens where space is available, and no stand-off if the screen is too small, then add the constraint, but put it a a lower priority.  Say 750 or 500.